# Gradle buildConfigField value received from terminal

Tags: android, gradle

I want to run my Android tests from console by using for example:

```
./gradlew testRun -PconfigVariable=true
```

Based on the configVariable I would like to create usable in project boolean variable with true/false value which will be used to set config in my test.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        (...)
        if (isSentValueTrue() == true) {
            println("Value is: " + isSentValueTrue())
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SENT_VALUE", "true"
        } else {
            println("Value is: " + isSentValueTrue())
            buildConfigField "boolean", "SENT_VALUE", "false"
        }
    }
    (...)
}

def isSentValueTrue() {
    def sentValue = project.getProperties().get("configVariable")
    return sentValue == null ? false : sentValue;
}
```

Consequently after I invoke presented above terminal command I get my BuildConfig.SENT_VALUE created in the project and I can use it. But what goes wrong is:

1. I type in terminal

   ```
   ./gradlew testRun -PconfigVariable=true
   ```
2. Test runs and BuildConfig.SENT_VALUE is set to true (println says that it entered 1st block of "if statement" in defaultConfig)
3. Test finish
4. I try to start test again with changing value of configVariable to false (println says that it entered 2nd block of "if statement" in defaultConfig)

   ```
   ./gradlew testRun -PconfigVariable=false
   ```
5. Test runs and BuildConfig.SENT_VALUE is still true even though

   ```
   buildConfigField "boolean", "SENT_VALUE", "false"
   ```

   was invoked in gradle but my variable in project didn't update.

What am I doing wrong or is there any other way to achieve the same effect? (send boolean through terminal into android project variable - so it is updated every time terminal command is changed)

Comment: are you using "instant run" or a cache and getting a stale value of your var as a result? use the --info  or other switch to get more details on your build config.

Comment: In my project each time I update buildConfigField I need to resync the whole project, so the new fields are generated in a class. This might suggest that your solution can't possibly work unless you get the project to  sync before running the tests.

Comment: I will try to sync project from console terminal then before it builds test and run.

Answer (score 0):

I think Gradle is not aware of your changes and doesn't rerun `generateDebugBuildConfig` task. You can check it by looking at Gradle output when running tests for the second time. This task should be `UP-TO-DATE`. There're a few simple way to make it work.

1. Clean the whole project before running a test.

   `./gradlew clean testRun -PconfigVariable=false`
2. Clean just the generation task. But you have to specify it's build variant properly. Here's how you can do it for a debug build with no flavors.

   `./gradlew cleaGenerateDebugBuildConfig testRun -PconfigVariable=false`
3. Force tasks to rerun by specifying `--rerun-tasks` flag.

   `./gradlew testRun -PconfigVariable=false --rerun-tasks`